# MySQL and deleting several rows with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using MySQL. I would like to delete all matches which `chart_id = 12` and `places.match_no > 104`.

Anyway, my query is not working. I cannot see what is the reason.

```
DELETE FROM matches
  INNER JOIN places ON places.id = matches.place_id
    AND places.match_no > 104
WHERE matches.chart_id = 12
```

This will cause an error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN places ON places' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the table you want to delete from:

```
DELETE m
    FROM matches m INNER JOIN
         places p
         ON p.id = m.place_id AND p.match_no > 104
    WHERE m.chart_id = 12;
```

The table name/alias goes between the `DELETE` and the `FROM`.

This is clearly explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

> Multiple-Table Syntax
>
> ```
> DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
>     tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
>     FROM table_references
>     [WHERE where_condition]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
DELETE FROM matches
WHERE matches.chart_id = 12 and matches.place_id in 
(select place_id 
 from places 
 where match_no > 104
)
```

Comment: Is this faster than the other way offered by @GordonLinoff?

Comment: I guess Gordon is always faster :)

Comment: I dare to say that the solutions are equivalent from the efficiency perspective

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
    DELETE m
    FROM matches m INNER JOIN
    places p
    ON p.id = m.place_id
    WHERE m.chart_id = 12 AND p.match_no > 104
```